# Writing a test for a provider that depends on another provider, if overrideWithValue in not available

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I am trying to write some tests, but I cannot override "properly" a provider that another provider depends on. The method overrideWithValue(), is not available on the provider that needs to be overridden.

The provider I am trying to test is this:

```
@riverpod
List<Point<double>> getItersectionsOnAxes(GetItersectionsOnAxesRef ref) {
  final constraints = ref.watch(dataEntryControllerProvider.select((value) => value.constraints));
  // logic that uses constraints variable and the return statement
}
```

The provider I need to override is this:

```
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
class DataEntryController extends _$DataEntryController {
  @override
  DataEntryModel build() {
    //initialization and return statement
  }
  
  //methods to mutate state
}
```

On the test file, when I try use the method `overrideWithValue()`, does not show as available. Only `overrideWith()` is available, but it does not allow to provide a value.

```
test('getItersectionsOnAxes', () {
      final overrides = <Override>[
        dataEntryControllerProvider.overrideWith(() {
          return DataEntryController();
          // ..state = const DataEntryModel(
          //   objective: Objectives.max,
          //   objectiveFunction: [180, 90],
          //   operators: [Operators.geq, Operators.geq, Operators.geq],
          //   constraints: [
          //     [6, 8, 48],
          //     [1, 0, 6],
          //     [0, 1, 4],
          //   ],
          // ),
        }),
      ];
      final container = createProviderContainer(overrides: overrides);
      final getIntersectionsOnAxes = container.read(getItersectionsOnAxesProvider);
      expect(getIntersectionsOnAxes, [const Point<double>(6 / 1, 0)]);
    });
```

The commented code, was me trying to supply a value.

```
 ProviderContainer createProviderContainer({
      ProviderContainer? parent,
      List<Override> overrides = const [],
      List<ProviderObserver>? observers,
    }) {
      final container = ProviderContainer(
        parent: parent,
        overrides: overrides,
        observers: observers,
      );
      addTearDown(() => container.dispose());
      return container;
    }
```

> The closure on the override, according to the docs is supposed to provide a ref argument, but it not behaving like that for me.

[image: docs overrideWith]

If there is anything I am doing wrong here, or need to change for it to work, I would appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OverrideWith` works just like `OverrideWithProvider` (there is no OverrideWithValue for NotifierProviderImpl for now, maybe because you don't just use a value, but a whole class to control your new provider) and the function doesn't pass a ref the same way NotifierProvider doesn't really have it in the constructor, its part of the class.

You need to create a mock or extends your class `DataEntryController` with your test functions and pass it to override:

```
class MockDataEntry extends DataEntryController {
  @override
  DataEntryModel build() {
    //initialization with your mock value, you can use ref here
    return const DataEntryModel(
       objective: Objectives.max,
       objectiveFunction: [180, 90],
       operators: [Operators.geq, Operators.geq, Operators.geq],
       constraints: [
         [6, 8, 48],
         [1, 0, 6],
         [0, 1, 4],
       ],
     );
  }

}

final overrides = <Override>[
  dataEntryControllerProvider.overrideWith(MockDataEntry.new),
];
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @EdwynZN. I would have never figured this out on my own. I am trying  your answer now.

Comment: Tried it, and it actually worked. Thank you so much!